# Faces disappearing based on view direction

Tags: three.js, transparency

I have a set of models generated from scientific data that I'm rendering using Threejs. The models are transparent and have internal shells that are a part of the mesh but not connected to the exterior/main shell.

If you view the models from the right side all of the internal shells are rendered and everything looks great (see second image). However, if you slowly rotate from left to right you can see tris progressively disappear (see the first image).

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

[image: Mouse brain missing internal structures]
[image: Mouse brain showing internal structures]

Comment: can they be back-facing? can you draw the normals?

Comment: Start by reading about the issue -- particularly self-transparency. https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bthree.js%5d%20transparent%20user%3a1461008. If necessary, I would suggest rendering the inner-shell as opaque, and only the outer shell as transparent.

Comment: @gaitat it's not a backfacing issue, the result is the same with or without double-side.

Comment: @WestLangley Both shells are a part of the same mesh and separating them isn't possible as we have 1500 meshes all generated from research data. 

I've looked through the transparency issues here and about a million blog posts, but so far nothing seems to deal with this issue directly. Does this stick out as something you've seen before?

Comment: Yes, self-transparency artifacts.

Comment: Turn off the depth buffer

Comment: What @gman is suggesting is similar to setting `material.depthWrite = false`. You must decide if that is acceptable for your application.

Comment: Not a trivial problem. For this kind of visualization, this kind of a technique can be useful https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth_peeling

Comment: @pailhead, thanks for the reply. I've been looking into IOT/Depth peeling and I have to say it is definitely non trivial.

Comment: Three.js does make it a lot easier though :)

Comment: Sadly it does not, the issue is largely browser support. Seems like you're just hosed if you want real transparency outside Chrome/Firefox... as IE, EDGE, Safari, etc do not support multiple frame buffers.